# URL not updating when iterating through URLs

Tags: python, html, selenium, loops, url

The following code does the following:

1 Opens a specific URL (for the first date YYYY-MM-DD);

2 getURL() generates all URLs with all dates in a specific date range (starting from the second day);

3 Opens new tab with the first date generated by getURL();

4 Goes back to previous tab and closes it;

5 Repeat steps 3 and 4.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load Chrome driver and movement.uber.com/cities website
PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)


# Attributing the city name and the center-most zone code (or origin) to variables so they can be inserted in the URL later
city = 'atlanta'
origin_code = '1074'
coordinates = '&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12'


# Open URL for the first day in the desired city (change coordinates depending on city)
driver.get('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' + 
           '2016-01-02' + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + '2016-01-02' + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=' + coordinates + '&lang=en-US')


# Generating the correct URLs for each date
def getURL():
    date = datetime(2016,1,4)
    while date <= datetime(2020,3,31):
        yield ('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' +
               date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12&lang=en-US')
        date += timedelta(days=1)

# Open new tab
i = 0
for url in getURL():
    i += 1
    if i < 3:
        driver.execute_script("window.open(url)")

        # Switch to previous tab and close it (leaving us with the newly above opened tab)
        tabs = driver.window_handles

        if len(tabs) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

The problem: every time a new tab/"window" is opened, the code opens the URL with the first date YYYY-MM-DD, completely ignoring the URLs generated by getURL().

The question: how do I open a new tab with the next date, close the previous one, repeat?

My ultimate goal: to download datasets that are inside each distinct URL (but the code for that is irrelevant for the problem here). Obs.: I use the Selenium library for that.

Comment: What is the value of `i` after the code executes?

Comment: If I add a print(i) to the last if statement, it first prints 1, then 2. If I add inside the for loop, it gives me 1549. It iterated from 1 through 1549 for whatever reason. Maybe that's the total number of URLs generated?

Comment: Is this line right? `driver.execute_script("window.open(url)")`   - that's passing in a string `url` and not the value.  i can't see how that would open a tab to any location

Comment: But I guess that's the only line of code that actually opens a new tab, no? If I run the code, it actually opens a new tab, it's just that it is always opening with 2016-01-02, which is the very first date. It is not moving on to 2016-01-03.

Comment: Your code runs fine after that JS error is fixed in `execute_script`.  IF the posted answer works and you're now online then awesome, ignore this comment.  If you're still struggling then let me know. Tell me how you're executing the script  - my VSCode caught the JS error and now it runs with no other changes needed..... I boosted `i` to 10 and i got 10 URLs with the date iterated. Your code is great :-)

Comment: Your answer submission worked. however, I still have a question that I added to the comments underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies on how you're launching a tab.

When i changed FROM:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open(url)")
```

TO:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"','_blank')")
```

The script executed perfectly on my machine.

It looks like `url` inside your approach is not updated on the iteration. If you make it into a parameter of the for loop it is resolved each time.

Have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for more info on javascript on how to open a window (FYI - you can also do `_self` instead of `_blank` to replace the current window - this might mitigate your need for tab management).

Results of my test...

This is the first iteration:

[image: first iteration]

This is the second iteration:

[image: second iteration]

---

For reference This is the entire script i ran:  (note that i updated `i` for more iterations, the chromedriver `PATH` for my machine + added couple of `print`s)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Load Chrome driver and movement.uber.com/cities website
#PATH = ''# - mine lives local -> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Attributing the city name and the center-most zone code (or origin) to variables so they can be inserted in the URL later
city = 'atlanta'
origin_code = '1074'
coordinates = '&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12'


# Open URL for the first day in the desired city (change coordinates depending on city)
driver.get('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' + 
           '2016-01-02' + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + '2016-01-02' + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=' + coordinates + '&lang=en-US')


# Generating the correct URLs for each date
def getURL():
    date = datetime(2016,1,4)
    while date <= datetime(2020,3,31):
        yield ('https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' +
               date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12&lang=en-US')
        date += timedelta(days=1)

# Open new tab
i = 0
print("urls: %i", len(list(getURL())))
for url in getURL():
    i += 1
    if i < 10:
        driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"','_blank')")
        print (url)
        # Switch to previous tab and close it (leaving us with the newly above opened tab)
        tabs = driver.window_handles

        if len(tabs) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[0])
            driver.close()
            driver.switch_to.window(tabs[1])
```

Comment: this is great thank you so much!! Another question though: as I mentioned at the bottom of the post, my goal is to do some more code, that is, do a couple more click inside that loop to get the data I need. The code I have for clicking on the button is: time.sleep(3)
download_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.f5 button') 
download_button.click()

The error I get is: "element click intercepted". I am inserting this piece of code just under:
driver.execute_script("window.open('"+url+"','_blank')")
print(url)

Why can I not click again on the button in the next tab?

Comment: click intercepted means there's something on top of your button.  - when i go to your base URL there's an "understanding origin" popup that's blocking access to the page behind it. Do you handle that? (press skip)  - & AFTER you handle it, are you waiting for your button to be available (i.e. using webdriverwait is the correct way but sleep is quick way to validate it is sync related)

Comment: Oh, true!! I forgot about the skip button. I will try adding the piece of code I have to click on the skip button. Thank you! The page loads so quickly I didn't notice the pop up. Let me try.

Comment: Interesting. When I open the new tab, the Understanding Origin window/pop up never appears. Even by pasting the code I have to close the window BEFORE the download_button one, it doesn't work :/

Comment: Tabs are more difficult as they have a a shared state. Your actions on the first tab can influence the next tab. I've not checked but you might only news to click the button once the first time you visit.... But if its another question you need support with then post a new question and folks can chip in :-)

Comment: Cool, I will make a new post right now. But thanks a lot! You solves pretty much 95% of my problem. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

you can maybe try to put all the urls you create in a list and then return it
like this :

```
def getURL():
    tab = []
    date = datetime(2016,1,4)
    while date <= datetime(2020,3,31):
        url ='https://movement.uber.com/explore/' + city + '/travel-times/query?si' + origin_code + '&ti=&ag=taz&dt[tpb]=ALL_DAY&dt[wd;]=1,2,3,4,5,6,7&dt[dr][sd]=' +
               date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&dt[dr][ed]=' + date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '&cd=&sa;=&sdn=&lat.=33.7489&lng.=-84.4234622&z.=12&lang=en-US'
        tab.append(url)
        date += timedelta(days=1)
    return tab
```

Comment: Awesome! One question, though: does this code take into consideration the fact that February, for example, sometimes has 28 or 29 days? Or does it completely ignore it and just jumps the next day until 31?

Comment: I think that since you use the datetime class, it takes into account the 28 or 29 days of the month of February, you can try printing all the dates to see the result